# IPhone- Rss sample code, modify to display images... PLease help!

Tags: xml, parsing, rss, uiimageview, nsxmlparser

I am trying to make app that displays an RSS feed, with text and images into  a table, but I am really struggeling with it!

I found a really good [sample code-project][1]  that i can really recommend-- but im struggeling getting it to display images in the tablecells instead of only text

I would be reeeeally happy with any help!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add an [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to your table's cells, and set it's `image` property to your images.
You'd want to do this in your [cellForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:) method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *MyIdentifer = @“MyIdentifier”;

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

  if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero 
        reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(3,3,75,75)];
    imgView.tag = 7;
  }


  [cell setText: (NSString*)[yourTextArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

  UIImageView *theImgView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag: 7];
  theImgView.image = (UIImage*)[yourImageArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]


  return cell;
}
```

Check out [this article](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/) for an asynchronous approach.